# SQL SELECT / CASE query with multiple columns returns System Error: &H80040E14 (-2147217900)

Tags: sql, excel, vba, select, case

Good morning,

I am having trouble with using `CASE` in a `SELECT` statement. The code works fine without it, even testing out the `CHARINDEX` works out. I've also substituted the code for more simpler `CASE` statements.

What I am trying to do is `SELECT` two columns with an additional place-holder column in a different location depending on if `a.AH_NAME1` contains the string "KGa". The reason for this is because I'm automating a pre-existing Excel worksheet wherein they have values for non-inhouse orders one column over. That is where `'' AS placeholder` comes in.

My error message is

> System Error: &H80040E14 (-2147217900)

```
strSQL = "SELECT a.ID, a.AH_NAME1, b.FI_PREIS_ME, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('KGa', a.AH_NAME1) > 0 THEN (b.FI_NETTO, '' AS placeholder, a.DATUM_ERF) ELSE ('' AS placeholder, b.FI_NETTO, a.DATUM_ERF) END AS CHARGEA, CHARGEB, DATUM_ERF "
        strSQL = strSQL & "FROM SYSADM.BW_AUFTR_KOPF a JOIN SYSADM.BW_AUFTR_POS b ON a.ID = b.ID "
        strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE b.PROD_ID = '99999999' "
        strSQL = strSQL & "AND a.STATUS BETWEEN 110 AND 860 "
        strSQL = strSQL & "AND MONTH(a.DATUM_ERF) BETWEEN " & Month(StartofMonth) & " AND " & Month(EndofMonth)
        strSQL = strSQL & "AND YEAR(a.DATUM_ERF) BETWEEN " & Year(StartofMonth) & " AND " & Year(EndofMonth)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your `select`:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.AH_NAME1, b.FI_PREIS_ME,
       (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('KGa', a.AH_NAME1) > 0
             THEN (b.FI_NETTO, '' AS placeholder, a.DATUM_ERF)
             ELSE ('' AS placeholder, b.FI_NETTO, a.DATUM_ERF)
        END) AS CHARGEA,
       CHARGEB, DATUM_ERF "
```

Sorry, you can't do this.  I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do.  But, if you want to return multiple values, you need a separate expression for each one.  `case` is an expression, and expressions produce only one value.  Perhaps this is what you want:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.AH_NAME1, b.FI_PREIS_ME,
       (CASE WHEN a.AH_NAME1 LIKE '%KGa%' THEN FI_NETTO ELSE ''
        END) as FI_NETTO,
       (CASE WHEN a.AH_NAME1 LIKE '%KGa%' THEN '' ELSE FI_NETTO
        END) as placeholder,
       DATUM_ERF as ChargeA,
       . . .
```

I replaced the `charindex()` with `like` simply because I prefer standard SQL, especially when the expression is shorter.